# ColdFusion - How to access CFC return variables in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfc

I am using ColdFusion 9 and jQuery.  I am using CFAJAXPROXY.

I have am having trouble accessing the data returned to a jQuery object.

This is part of my jQuery code:

```
var jro = new jsApp();
NewUser = jro.addUser(NewEmail);
```

The method in the CFC is addUser. I pass in an Email address (NewEmail) and I get the new user's UserID back.

This query in the CFC works just fine:

```
<cfquery name="GetUserID">
SELECT      MAX(UserID) as MaxID
FROM        Users
</cfquery>
```

When I hard code a value like this, I do not have a problem:

```
<cfset NewUser = 10>
<cfreturn NewUser>
```

When I try to use a dynamic variable like this, I get a JSON error:

```
<cfset NewUser = GetUserID.MaxID>
<cfreturn NewUser>
```

This error seems to occur in the CFC. Hard coding the return variable works, but returning a single integer from a query does NOT work.

How do I return a single integer from a query? Why is this creating a problem?

Here is the how the CFC is called.

```
$("#AddUserSave").click(function() {
  NewEmail = $("#NewEmail").attr("value");
  var jro = new jsApp();
  UserID = jro.addUser(NewEmail);
  $("#UserDiv").load("GlobalAdmin/EditUser.cfm?UserID="+UserID);
});
```

Again, the CFC refuses to return the UserID from the database, but gladly returns a hardcoded number.

Okay, in my CFC this works:

```
<cfset NewUser = GetUserID.UserID>
<cfset NewUser = 1>
<cfreturn NewUser>
```

But this does NOT work:

```
<cfset NewUser = GetUserID.UserID>
<cfreturn NewUser>
```

Firebug says:

```
parseJSON throw new SyntaxError("parseJSON"); 
cfajax.js (line 803)
```

Okay, when I access this method via the browser, it shows an integer being returned.

```
 <!--- GET MAX USER --->
 <cffunction name="getMaxUser" access="remote" returnformat="plain" returntype="any">
    <cfquery name="GetUserID">
        SELECT  MAX(UserID) AS MaxID
        FROM    Users
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn createObject( 'java', 'java.lang.Integer' ).init( javaCast( 'int', GetUserID.MaxID ) ) />
</cffunction>
```

When I view the page source, the maxid is 1 (one / an integer).

The CFC is being called with in JavaScript:

```
    var jro = new jsApp();
    jro.getMaxUser();
```

The exact error I am getting can be viewed on this screen shot:

http://evikjames.com/IMAGEs/parsejson.png

And here's an image of my CFCs.

http://evikjames.com/images/CFC.png

Here's an image of the URL created by JavaScript to access the method:

http://www.evikjames.com/images/error-2.png

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ANSWER

The JavaScript needs to create a request that sets the return format to plain. I guess its default return type is JSON. The CFC chokes on the JSON that it own self has created.

```
var jro = new jsApp();
jro.setReturnFormat('plain');
UserID = jro.getMaxUser();
```

Hats off to Charlie for seeing this through.  I am forever grateful.

Comment: Can you use Firebug or something similar to verify that the value being returned is numeric?  I ran a quick test and it seems to work, but I recall that there were situations where you needed to use array notation to reference a query value like that... `<cfset NewUser = GetUserID.MaxID[ 1 ] />` for example.

Comment: No value is being returned.  <cfset NewUser = GetUserID.MaxID>
<cfreturn NewUser> causes a JSON error in the CFC.  Your idea seems like it might return a single value instead of an array/structure/query, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you confirm though, that when you just do <cfreturn 10 />, it works as expected?  If so, that would suggest that the issue is somewhere in how you're referencing the query value.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that this works:  When I hard code a value like this, I do not have a problem:

<cfset NewUser = 10>
<cfreturn NewUser>

Comment: OK then... the question of "How do I access the data that is returned to jQuery" is not the right question, since you know you can access it properly.  The question is, "how do I get the maxID value and return it?".  Can you dump `newUser` and abort, then use Firebug to check the exact value that you're setting it to?

Comment: Somewhat along the same line as Jason Dean's question... I'm not sure why you're using both cfajaxproxy and jQuery.  Is there a reason you need cfajp?  Can't you just use jQuery's $.ajax() method?  I'm wondering if mixing the two is complicating matters.

Comment: You are correct: I had the question wrong.  Yes, your modified question is correct.  You CAN'T dump within a CFC. I have tested the query in SQL Server and it works just fine. It just returns a silly little number every time.  I'll check it again though.

Comment: You can dump within a CFC.  In fact, since the method is (presumably) remote, you can do the dump, the abort, and call the CFC directly in a browser via `http://domain/name_of_cfc.cfc?method=yourmethod`

Comment: incidentally, is it safe to assume that you have a datasource attribute in your cfquery, and that the code above was just typed out and omitted that attribute for the sake of brevity? :)

Comment: You don't need to specify a datasource in your query in CF9. I am using the THIS scope.

Comment: @charliegriefer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2471/discussion-between-evik-james-and-charliegriefer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our chat, you need your remotely accessible method to return an integer, not a float.

With credit to http://www.threesources.com/archives/009007.html, you need to do the following:

1) specify returnFormat = "plain" (which I believe you've done)

2) `<cfreturn createObject( 'java', 'java.lang.Integer' ).init( javaCast( 'int', GetUserID.MaxID ) ) />`

As per the site linked to above, the reason is, "ColdFusion's Numeric type maps to a double in the automatically generated RPC WSDL".

That site lists 5 steps that need to be taken, but I was able to successfully return an integer by just doing the 2 steps listed above.

Comment: This solution works flawlessly when I access the CFC in the browser (http://127.0.0.1:8500/WebSites/ReviewManager/GlobalAdmin/users.cfc?method=addUser&NewEmail=evd2mes@gopd.com). I get the new UserID returned. It doesn't work in site though, even after rebooting. Ugh.

Comment: Need more to go on than "doesn't work in the site".  What's firebug saying is being returned?  What's the error message (assuming there's an error)?

Comment: Please update the question again with the exact code you're using to do the `<cfreturn>`

Comment: Just so folks playing along at home are kept up-to-date... as discussed in chat, cfajaxproxy sends requests with a returnFormat=JSON by default.  This overrides your returnFormat="plain" (as per bullet point 1 above).

In your JS, you need to specify that cfajaxproxy uses a returnFormat of plain.  `var jro = new jsApp(); jro.setReturnFormat( 'plain' ); jro.getMaxUser();`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are accessing the returned data as a JavaScript array. I don't know how you are making your call, but it looks like you are only returning a number, how is the JSON formatting coming through?

It has been a while since I have done this stuff, but if you are simply doign an $.ajax() call, then I think the value would simply be in the "data" variable.  Have you tried simply alert(data)?  Does it contain the number?

By calling NewUser.DATA[0][0] you are saying that you have a variable call NewUser with the JSON equivalent of [[number]].

How are you making your call in JavaScript and what does the return JSON actually look like (you shoul dbe able to see it in FireBug or other browser debug tools)?